# Laravel - post route methodNotAllowed

Tags: laravel, post, routes

I have this methodNotAllowed problem in a laravel project when using a post request to update the db.

ItemController which has an update method but also a another customUpdate method:

```
public function updateQuantityIncrement(Request $request, Item $item){
    //save data
    Log::info('This is some useful information.');
    $itemUpdate = Item::where('id',$item->id)->update([
        'name' => $item->name,
        'articleNo' => $item->articleNo,
        'source' => $item->source,
        'menge' => $item->menge + 1,
        'img_path' => $item->img_path,
    ]);

    if($itemUpdate){
        return redirect()->route('items.show', ['item' => $item])
            ->with('success', 'Artikel erfolgreich Aktualisiert!');
        //return redirect()->route('items.show',['item'=>$item])->with('success','Artikel erfolgreich Aktualisiert!');
    }
    //redirect
    //if fails
    return back()->withInput();
}
```

The normal update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Item $item){
    //save data
    $itemUpdate = Item::where('id',$item->id)->update([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'articleNo' => $request->input('articleNo'),
        'source' => $request->input('source'),
        'menge' => $request->input('menge'),
        'img_path' => $request->input('img_path'),
    ]);

    if($itemUpdate){
        return redirect()->route('items.show',['item'=>$item])->with('success','Artikel erfolgreich Aktualisiert!');
    }
    //redirect
    //if fails
    return back()->withInput();
}
```

html from code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('items.updateQuantityIncrement',[$item->id]) }}">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">+</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><br><br><br>
                                </form>
```

In my web.route file i have above resource route this:

```
Route::post('items/{item}/updateQuantityIncrement', 'ItemController@updateQuantityIncrement')
->name('items.updateQuantityIncrement');
```

Resource route:

```
Route::resource('items', 'ItemController');
```

I also tried this approach:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'items/{item}/updateQuantityIncrement', [
'as' => 'items.updateQuantityIncrement',
'uses' => 'ItemController@updateQuantityIncrement']);
```

But with that it is the same error.

Error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 255)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 242)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)
```

Can someone help me to understand this behaviour?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: remove ``<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">`` from the form!

Comment: ohhhh thank you this works finally .. cn you also explain me why i thought i would need this .
Thanks

Comment: Quoting from [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing) ``HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form.``

Comment: Ok but this was actually hidden and name was _method so what is the issue?

Comment: That's how Laravel makes it PUT request behind the scene!

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::put('items/{item}/updateQuantityIncrement','ItemController@updateQuantityIncrement')->name('items.updateQuantityIncrement');
```

1. replace post method with put method in your `route`.
2. add this to your form : `@method('put')`.